# How to remeasure layout_weight?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-layout-weight

In the layout xml below I'm creating a horizontal `LinearLayout` with two child views. The `LinearLayout` child is supposed to stretch its width dynamically, the `ImageView` has its width depending on the parent's height.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Some children ... -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <MyAspectRatioImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is a result like this:

[image: manipulated screenshot]

But what I actually get is:

[image: original screenshot]

This is because in my custom `ImageView` I overrode `onMeasure` to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio (simplified):

```
override def onMeasure( widthMeasure: Int, heightMeasure: Int )
{
    super.onMeasure( widthMeasure, heightMeasure )

    setMeasuredDimensions( height, height )
}
```

Now I'd need the parent view to recalculate the width share with the new ImageView width in mind. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I solved the issue with an implementation of `onMeasure` that does not call `super`. Its highly focused on the described scenario and may break easily when used elsewhere. Also the code is in Scala, sorry about that.

```
override def onMeasure( widthMeasure: Int, heightMeasure: Int )
{
    ( Option( getDrawable ), ( getMode( widthMeasure ), getMode( heightMeasure ) ) ) match
    {
        // No Drawable
        case ( None, _ ) => setMeasuredDimensions( 0, 0 )
        // Width and height are known
        case ( _, ( EXACTLY, EXACTLY ) ) =>
        {
            // Determine which axis to adjust for the ratio
            val ( width, height ) = ratio.getDominance match
            {
                case 0 => ( getSize( widthMeasure ), ( getSize( widthMeasure ) * ratio.getValue ).toInt )
                case 1 => ( ( getSize( heightMeasure ) * ratio.getValue ).toInt, getSize( heightMeasure ) )
            }

            setMeasuredDimensions( width, height )

            // This call makes this whole thing work in first place
            if( getAdjustViewBounds )
            {
                getLayoutParams.width = width
                getLayoutParams.height = height
            }
        }
        // Only height dimension is known, adjust width to ratio
        case ( _, ( _, EXACTLY ) ) =>
        {
            val height = getSize( heightMeasure )
            setMeasuredDimensions( ( height * ratio.getValue ).toInt, height )
        }
        // Only width dimension is known, adjust height to ratio
        case ( _, ( EXACTLY, _ ) ) =>
        {
            val width = getSize( widthMeasure )
            setMeasuredDimensions( ( width * ratio.getValue ).toInt, width )
        }
        case ( Some( drawable ), ( UNSPECIFIED, UNSPECIFIED ) ) =>
        {
            val ( width, height ) = ratio.getDominance match
            {
                case 0 => ( drawable.getIntrinsicWidth, ( drawable.getIntrinsicWidth * ratio.getValue ).toInt )
                case 1 => ( ( drawable.getIntrinsicHeight * ratio.getValue ).toInt, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight )
            }

            setMeasuredDimensions( width, height )
        }
        case ( Some( drawable ), ( UNSPECIFIED, _ ) ) =>
        {
            setMeasuredDimensions(
                ( drawable.getIntrinsicWidth * ratio.getValue ).toInt,
                drawable.getIntrinsicWidth
            )
        }
        case ( Some( drawable ), ( _, UNSPECIFIED ) ) =>
        {
            setMeasuredDimensions(
                ( drawable.getIntrinsicHeight * ratio.getValue ).toInt,
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight
            )
        }
        case _ => super.onMeasure( widthMeasure, heightMeasure )
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Taig/Toolbelt/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/taig/android/widget/image/AspectRatio.scala